# Change Admin Account of Fabric

Tags: twitter-fabric, google-fabric

I tried to change admin account to my own.
Because the person who has the admin account has left. Our company is using Gmail as a corporate email, and unfortunately emails of people with admin accounts have been deleted.

Let me know what I can do

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! For this you will need to contact support through your Fabric dashboard. We will have two people from your organization verify that we can change someone to admin. After that you'll be back up and running. Thanks! -Todd from Fabric